# pushout with zero upper map

Tags: diagram-chasing

If 
\begin{array}{ccC}
A &\xrightarrow {0} & B\\
\downarrow & &\downarrow \\
C & \xrightarrow{g} & D
\end{array}
is a pushout. is $g$ zero map?

Comment: I guess $g$ is rather the cokernel of $A\to C$.

Comment: What category is this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for example
\begin{array}{ccC}
0 & \to & B\\
\downarrow & &\downarrow \\
C & \xrightarrow{g} & B \oplus C
\end{array}
is a pushout with $g$ the "inclusion", in say vector spaces.

Comment: Indeed your diagram is a correct pushout in any category with binary coproducts where $B\oplus C$ stands for $B\sqcup C$ and $0$ stands for an initial object

Comment: @FShrike Is it clear in that generality that $g \ne 0$?

Comment: Not assuming the category has a zero object, i.e. only assuming $0$ is initial and perhaps not terminal, that would imply that if there exists an arrow $B\to X$ there exists at most one arrow $C\to X$, and existence of an arrow $C\to 0$ would entail $C\to0\to X$ surely always exists and therefore that $B\oplus C\cong B$. This isn't enough to show $C=0$ though, I don't think. Hmm. But if you live in a category where the binary coproduct inclusions are monomorphisms then $g$ is zero iff. $C$ is isomorphic to $0$, we can say that